# Replacing data in text

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple rows of data separated by commas that look like the following:

```
110,2024010,37345,5435493,0,"1234","431","asdf||asdf|adf","Gdańsk||rwet|ertwe ewrtw",0,1444476,"value1","","","51"
110,2024010,70014,5434593,0,"1234","431","asdf||asdf|adf","Kraków||rwet|ertwe ewrtw",0,19444476,"value2","","","51"
```

and i want to replace all "valueX" between 11 and 12th comma to the same value in every row.

Value1 and Value2 contain a lot of unwanted data that is important for another team (e.g., usernames), we want to keep it simple, the same value in each import to make sorting easier.

I want Value1 and Value2 to be replaced to new one Value3

I use csv library: import csv and was testing pandas module

Comment: Is your input the CSV file? What exactly is the expected output? And logic?

Comment: its file without extension that i got from another team that i import to my program,

Comment: And what are the logic and expected output? Here you have `value1` and `value2`, what is the expected output and why?

Comment: Value1 and Value2 contain a lot of unwanted data that is important for another team (e.g., usernames), we want to keep it simple, the same value in each import to make sorting easier

Comment: So which value do you want?

Comment: i want Value1 and Value2 to be replaced to new one Value3

Comment: Please include all required minimal information in your question. See [mre] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
col_position = 11
new_value = 'Value3'

(pd.read_csv('input_csv', header=None)
   .rename(columns=str)
   .assign(**{str(col_position): new_value})
   .to_csv('output_csv', header=None, index=False)
)
```

In pure python with the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

col_position = 11
new_value = 'Value3'

with open('input_csv') as f_in, open('output_csv', 'w') as f_out:
    w = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=','):
        row[col_position] = new_value
        w.writerow(row)
```

Output file:

```
110,2024010,37345,5435493,0,1234,431,asdf||asdf|adf,Gdańsk||rwet|ertwe ewrtw,0,1444476,Value3,,,51
110,2024010,70014,5434593,0,1234,431,asdf||asdf|adf,Kraków||rwet|ertwe ewrtw,0,19444476,Value3,,,51
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said in above reply the file is not a csv file, so you can try below method using csv library.

```
import csv

input_file = 'input.csv'
output_file = 'output.csv'

new_value = "Value"

with open(input_file, 'r', newline='') as infile, open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    for row in reader:
        if len(row) >= 12:
            # Replace "Value1" and "Value2" with "Value3" in the 12th field
            row[11] = new_value if row[11] in ["value1", "value2"] else row[11]
        writer.writerow(row)

print("Replacement complete. Updated data saved to output.csv.")
```

Here you file will be saved as csv file.